# Как наложить водяной знак на фото при загрузке нескольких фото

Tags: php

Код который сохраняет на сервере сразу несколько загружаемых фото:

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$f) {
if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], "../img/cars/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$k])) {
    echo 'Файл: '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$k].' загружен.<br />';
  }
}
}
}
```

И есть функция наложения водяного знака на фото, которая должна сохранить загружаемое на сервер фото, уже с водяным знаком.

```
function watermark($file, $watermark) {

if(empty($file) | empty($watermark)) return false;

 $wh = getimagesize($watermark);
 $fh = getimagesize($file);
 $rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); 
 $rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

  imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[0], $wh[1]);
  imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80'); 
  imagedestroy($rwatermark);
  imagedestroy($rfile);

 return true;

}
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
function watermark($file, $watermark) {

if(empty($file) | empty($watermark)) return false;

 $wh = getimagesize($watermark);
 $fh = getimagesize($file);
 $rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); 
 $rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

  imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[0], $wh[1]);
  imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80'); 
  imagedestroy($rwatermark);
  imagedestroy($rfile);

 return true;

}

foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$f) {
if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {


  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], "$imgDir/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$k])) {
    echo 'Файл: '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$k].' загружен.<br />';
    $newfile = ''.$name.'';
  watermark($newfile, './waterMark.png');
  }


}
}
}
```

но водяной фото сохраняет без водяного знака.
Где я ошибся? Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых у вас тут опечатка, вместо логического ИЛИ используется побитовое ИЛИ

```
if(empty($file) | empty($watermark)) return false;
```

Замените на этот код

```
if(empty($file) || empty($watermark)) return false;
```

Во-вторых откуда вы взяли переменную `$name`?

```
$newfile = ''.$name.'';
```

У вас ее нет, соответсвенно и переменная `$newfile`, которую вы дальше используйте выглядит как пустая строка. Не забывайте смотреть логи, там наверняка есть `E_NOTICE`. И еще в коде не видно объявление переменной `$imgDir`.

Оставляя объявление переменной `$imgDir` за кадром, вот минимальный рефакторинг:

```
function watermark($file, $watermark)
{

    if (empty($file) || empty($watermark)) {
        return false;
    }

    $wh = getimagesize($watermark);
    $fh = getimagesize($file);
    $rwatermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);
    $rfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

    imagecopy($rfile, $rwatermark, $fh[0] - $wh[0], $fh[1] - $wh[1], 0, 0, $wh[0], $wh[1]);
    imagejpeg($rfile, $file, '80');
    imagedestroy($rwatermark);
    imagedestroy($rfile);

    return true;

}

foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k => $f) {
    if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
            $newfile = "$imgDir/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k];
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $newfile)) {
                echo 'Файл: ' . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k] . ' загружен.<br />';
                watermark($newfile, './waterMark.png');
            }
        }
    }
}
```